# Parsing "XML Spreadsheet 2003" into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-spreadsheet

I have 6000+ XML Spreadsheet files that I would like to parse into Pandas DataFrames. Preferably I would like to do this using the pd.read_xml method and provide the correct arguments (x-path?). I would like to stay away from parsing it using lxml. I need it to be as performant as possible.

An example of my file:

```
<?mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet'?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="ShortDate">
            <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="Titles">
            <Font ss:Bold="1"/>
            <Interior ss:Color="#C0C0C0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="ColorShortDate">
            <Font ss:Color="#808080"/>
            <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="MakeCellColor">
            <Font ss:Color="#808080"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="DateTimeStamp">
            <NumberFormat ss:Format="dd/mm/yyyy'' hh:mm:ss"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Details" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:Composites="Composites" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <Table>
            <Column ss:Width="114.75"/>
            <Column ss:Width="116.25"/>
            <Column ss:Width="53.25"/>
            <Column ss:Width="171.75"/>
            <Row ss:StyleID="Titles">
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ShortName</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">FieldCode</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Value</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Calculate</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">yes</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Calendar</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Working Days</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">FromCurrency</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">TranslatableName</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Inception</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ToCurrency</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">InceptionDate</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">1995-01-01</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CHF vs EUR</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">LastModificationDate</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">2011-08-19</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <Selected/>
            <FreezePanes/>
            <SplitHorizontal>1</SplitHorizontal>
            <TopRowBottomPane>1</TopRowBottomPane>
            <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The DataFrame I'm expecting would be:

| ShortName | FieldCode | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHF vs EUR | Calculate |  | yes |
| CHF vs EUR | Calendar |  | Working Days |
| CHF vs EUR | FromCurrency |  | EUR |
| CHF vs EUR | TranslatableName | Inception | CHF vs EUR |
| CHF vs EUR | ToCurrency |  | CHF |
| CHF vs EUR | InceptionDate |  | 1995-01-01 |
| CHF vs EUR | LastModificationDate |  | 2011-08-19 |

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use only pandas (even though [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) is used under the hood), you can try :

```
N = 4 # nb of cols
xp = ".//ss:Row/ss:Cell"
ns = {"ss": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}

tmp = pd.read_xml("file.xml", xpath=xp, namespaces=ns).squeeze()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(tmp[N:], (-1, N)), columns=tmp[:N]).fillna("")
```

Or this generic approach :

```
from lxml import etree

rows = etree.parse("file.xml").xpath(".//ss:Row", namespaces=ns)

headata = [[col.text for col in row.xpath(
    "./ss:Cell/ss:Data", namespaces=ns)] for row in rows]

df = pd.DataFrame(headata[1:], columns=headata[0]).fillna("")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

Data   ShortName             FieldCode       Date         Value
0     CHF vs EUR             Calculate                      yes
1     CHF vs EUR              Calendar             Working Days
2     CHF vs EUR          FromCurrency                      EUR
3     CHF vs EUR      TranslatableName  Inception    CHF vs EUR
4     CHF vs EUR            ToCurrency                      CHF
5     CHF vs EUR         InceptionDate               1995-01-01
6     CHF vs EUR  LastModificationDate               2011-08-19

[7 rows x 4 columns]
```